# Why won't Kibana Node server start up?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I just upgraded to Elasticsearch and Kibana 6.0.1 from 5.6.4 and I'm having trouble getting the Kibana server running. The service appears to be running, but nothing is binding to the port and I don't see any errors in the logs.

Verifying the version I have running:

```
root@my-server:/var/log# /usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana --version
6.0.1
```

Checking the service status:

```
root@my-server:/var/log# sudo service kibana start
root@my-server:/var/log# sudo service kibana status
● kibana.service - Kibana
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kibana.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-12-08 21:17:53 UTC; 1s ago
 Main PID: 17766 (node)
    Tasks: 6 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 86.6M
      CPU: 1.981s
   CGroup: /system.slice/kibana.service
           └─17766 /usr/share/kibana/bin/../node/bin/node --no-warnings /usr/share/kibana/bin/../src/cli -c /etc/kibana/kibana.yml
```

The contents of my /etc/kibana/kibana.yml config file:

```
elasticsearch.password: mypassword
elasticsearch.url: http://my-server:9200
elasticsearch.username: elastic
logging.dest: /var/log/kibana.log
logging.verbose: true
server.basePath: /kibana
server.host: localhost
server.port: 5601
```

The contents of my log file:

```
root@my-server:/var/log# tail /var/log/kibana.log -n1000
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:04Z","tags":["plugins","debug"],"pid":17712,"dir":"/usr/share/kibana/plugins","message":"Scanning `/usr/share/kibana/plugins` for plugins"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:04Z","tags":["plugins","debug"],"pid":17712,"dir":"/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins","message":"Scanning `/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins` for plugins"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:16Z","tags":["plugins","debug"],"pid":17712,"path":"/usr/share/kibana/plugins/x-pack/index.js","message":"Found plugin at /usr/share/kibana/plugins/x-pack/index.js"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:16Z","tags":["plugins","debug"],"pid":17712,"path":"/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/console/index.js","message":"Found plugin at /usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/console/index.js"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:16Z","tags":["plugins","debug"],"pid":17712,"path":"/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/elasticsearch/index.js","message":"Found plugin at /usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/elasticsearch/index.js"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:16Z","tags":["plugins","debug"],"pid":17712,"path":"/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/kbn_doc_views/index.js","message":"Found plugin at /usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/kbn_doc_views/index.js"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:16Z","tags":["plugins","debug"],"pid":17712,"path":"/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/kbn_vislib_vis_types/index.js","message":"Found plugin at /usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/kbn_vislib_vis_types/index.js"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:17Z","tags":["plugins","debug"],"pid":17712,"path":"/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/kibana/index.js","message":"Found plugin at /usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/kibana/index.js"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:17Z","tags":["plugins","debug"],"pid":17712,"path":"/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/markdown_vis/index.js","message":"Found plugin at /usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/markdown_vis/index.js"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:17Z","tags":["plugins","debug"],"pid":17712,"path":"/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/metrics/index.js","message":"Found plugin at /usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/metrics/index.js"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:17Z","tags":["plugins","debug"],"pid":17712,"path":"/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/region_map/index.js","message":"Found plugin at /usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/region_map/index.js"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:17Z","tags":["plugins","debug"],"pid":17712,"path":"/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/spy_modes/index.js","message":"Found plugin at /usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/spy_modes/index.js"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:17Z","tags":["plugins","debug"],"pid":17712,"path":"/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/state_session_storage_redirect/index.js","message":"Found plugin at /usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/state_session_storage_redirect/index.js"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:17Z","tags":["plugins","debug"],"pid":17712,"path":"/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/status_page/index.js","message":"Found plugin at /usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/status_page/index.js"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:17Z","tags":["plugins","debug"],"pid":17712,"path":"/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/table_vis/index.js","message":"Found plugin at /usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/table_vis/index.js"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:17Z","tags":["plugins","debug"],"pid":17712,"path":"/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/tagcloud/index.js","message":"Found plugin at /usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/tagcloud/index.js"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:17Z","tags":["plugins","debug"],"pid":17712,"path":"/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/tile_map/index.js","message":"Found plugin at /usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/tile_map/index.js"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:17Z","tags":["plugins","debug"],"pid":17712,"path":"/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/timelion/index.js","message":"Found plugin at /usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/timelion/index.js"}
{"type":"ops","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:18Z","tags":[],"pid":17712,"os":{"load":[1.03271484375,1.29541015625,2.1494140625],"mem":{"total":2094931968,"free":763858944},"uptime":10018},"proc":{"uptime":16.017,"mem":{"rss":269451264,"heapTotal":239005696,"heapUsed":200227592,"external":489126},"delay":3.2269310001283884},"load":{"requests":{},"concurrents":{"5601":0},"responseTimes":{},"sockets":{"http":{"total":0},"https":{"total":0}}},"message":"memory: 191.0MB uptime: 0:00:16 load: [1.03 1.30 2.15] delay: 3.227"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-12-08T21:17:18Z","tags":["info","optimize"],"pid":17712,"message":"Optimizing and caching bundles for graph, monitoring, ml, kibana, stateSessionStorageRedirect, timelion, login, logout, dashboardViewer and status_page. This may take a few minutes"}
```

Confirming that ES is up and running:

```
root@my-server:/var/log# curl -u elastic:"mypassword" http://my-
server:9200/
{
  "name" : "vf9xM-O",
  "cluster_name" : "my-server",
  "cluster_uuid" : "pdwwLfCOTgehc_5B8oB-8g",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.0.1",
    "build_hash" : "601be4a",
    "build_date" : "2017-12-04T09:29:09.525Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.0.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

When I try to CURL the Kibana Node server (which should be running on 5601 as per the config):

```
root@my-server:/var/log# curl 'localhost:5601'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5601: Connection refused
```

Indeed when I list the open ports, I see lots of things, but nothing on 5601:

```
root@my-server:/var/log# netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9191            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1412/uwsgi          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1413/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15924/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1519/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3031            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1412/uwsgi          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1591/postgres       
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      1413/systemd-resolv 
tcp6       0      0 :::9200                 :::*                    LISTEN      16108/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::9300                 :::*                    LISTEN      16108/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1519/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      1591/postgres
```

I'm not sure what else to try to troubleshoot Kibana, any ideas are really really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not really sure why, but this seemed to work after I rebooted the machine:

```
root@my-server:~# sudo reboot
```

after a minute I SSHed back in and voila:

```
root@my-server:~# netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5601          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1428/node           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9191            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1414/uwsgi          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1427/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1467/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1510/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3031            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1414/uwsgi          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1578/postgres       
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      1427/systemd-resolv 
tcp6       0      0 :::9200                 :::*                    LISTEN      2011/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::9300                 :::*                    LISTEN      2011/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1510/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      1578/postgres
```

**¯_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: The funny thing is, a year and a version later, I just ran into a similar situation, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56966684/