# Kibana stopped working and now server not getting ready although kibana.service starts up nicely

Tags: elasticsearch, service, kibana, elastic-stack

Without any major system update of my Ubuntu (`4.4.0-142-generic #168-Ubuntu SMP`), Kibana 7.2.0 stopped working. I am still able to start the service with `sudo systemctl start kibana.service` and the corresponding status looks fine. There is only a warning and no error, this does not seem to be the issue:

```
# sudo systemctl status kibana.service 
● kibana.service - Kibana
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kibana.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-07-10 09:43:49 CEST; 22min ago
 Main PID: 14856 (node)
    Tasks: 21
   Memory: 583.2M
      CPU: 1min 30.067s
   CGroup: /system.slice/kibana.service
           └─14856 /usr/share/kibana/bin/../node/bin/node --no-warnings --max-http-header-size=65536 /usr/share/kibana/bin/../src/cli -c /etc/kibana/kibana.yml

Jul 10 09:56:36 srv003 kibana[14856]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-07-10T07:56:36Z","tags":["warning","task_manager"],"pid":14856,"message":"The task maps_telemetry \"Maps-maps_telemetry\" is not cancellable."}
```

Nevertheless, when I visit `http://srv003:5601/` on my client machine, I keep seeing only (even after waiting 20 minutes):

```
Kibana server is not ready yet
```

On the server `srv003` itself, I see

```
me@srv003:# curl -XGET http://localhost:5601/status -I
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5601: Connection refused
```

This is a strange since Kibana seems to be really listening at that port and the firewall is disabled for testing purposes:

```
root@srv003# sudo lsof -nP -i | grep 5601
node      14856        kibana   18u  IPv4 115911041      0t0  TCP 10.0.0.72:5601 (LISTEN)
root@srv003# sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
```

There is nothing suspicious in the log of `kibana.service` either:

```
root@srv003:/var/log# journalctl -u kibana.service | grep -A 99 "Jul 10 10:09:14"
Jul 10 10:09:14 srv003 systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
Jul 10 10:09:38 srv003 kibana[14856]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-07-10T08:09:38Z","tags":["warning","task_manager"],"pid":14856,"message":"The task maps_telemetry \"Maps-maps_telemetry\" is not cancellable."}
```

My Elasticsearch is still up and running. There is nothing interesting in the corresponding log files about Kibana:

```
root@srv003:/var/log# cat elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log  |grep kibana
[2019-07-10T09:46:25,158][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataIndexTemplateService] [srv003] adding template [.kibana_task_manager] for index patterns [.kibana_task_manager]
[2019-07-10T09:47:32,955][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [srv003] [.monitoring-kibana-7-2019.07.10] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [.monitoring-kibana], shards [1]/[0], mappings [_doc]
```

Now I am running a bit out of options, and I hope somebody can give me another hint.

**Edit:** I do not have any Kibana plugins installed.

**Consulted sources:**

- [How to fix "Kibana server is not ready yet" error when using AKS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54577010/how-to-fix-kibana-server-is-not-ready-yet-error-when-using-aks)
- [Kibana service is running but can not access via browser to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855454/kibana-service-is-running-but-can-not-access-via-browser-to-console)
- [Why won't Kibana Node server start up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47722461/why-wont-kibana-node-server-start-up)
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/failed-to-start-kibana-7-0-1/180259/3 - most promising thread, but nobody ever answered
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-server-is-not-ready-yet-issue-after-upgrade-to-6-5-0/157021
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-server-not-ready/162075

Comment: kibana is not very stable. sometimes I reboot the server and problem has been solved. for last resort, I recommend to uninastall and install it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like if Kibana enters the described undefined state, a simple reboot of the computer is necessary. This is of course not acceptable for a (virtual or physical) machine where other services are running.